# RTCMultiConnection Demos cordva for IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, webrtc, rtcmulticonnection

We integrated RTCMultiConnection Demos cordva code in iOS app and also add iOS native code into it.
need to confirm one thing that how it will be linked with our web code i.e if i will call from my IOS app then how it will get connected within my website . Please confirm if possible and how.

Thanks in Advance plus Happy New Year

Answer (score 1):

Your cordova app sets [socketURL](http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/socketURL/):

connection.socketURL = 'https://domain.com:9001/';

Your cordova app has a file named as [loadRTCMultiConnection.js](http://webrtcweb.com/cordova-apps/scalable-broadcast/#loadRTCMultiConnection.js). This file MUST be using same RTCMultiConnection [distribution as the your web page](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/tree/master/dist).

#### Conclusion:

1. Your cordova app MUST set `socketURL` parameter
2. Your cordova app MUST be using same `RTCMultiConnection.js`

#### Explanation:

`socketURL` is used to access your socket.io server. Both cordova app and web-browsers are using same socket.io server.

---

### Updated at Jan 03, 2017

To use Firebase in the RTCMultiConnection-cordova-apps:

1. Open `index.html` and replace `socket.io.js` with `Firebase.js`
2. Add [this script](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/dev/globals.js) in the same index.html file: `<script src="js/globals.js"></script>`
3. Add [this script](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/dev/FirebaseConnection.js) in the same HTML file: `<script src="js/FirebaseConnection.js"></script>`
4. Opne [index.js](http://webrtcweb.com/cordova-apps/video-conferencing/#index.js) and add this line: `connection.setCustomSocketHandler(FirebaseConnection);`
5. As well as this line: `connection.firebase = 'webrtc-experiment';`

To recap it:

```
<!-- index.html file -->
<script src="js/Firebase.js"></script>
<script src="js/globals.js"></script>
<script src="js/FirebaseConnection.js"></script>
```

and:

```
// index.js

var connection = new RTCMultiConnection();

connection.setCustomSocketHandler(FirebaseConnection);
connection.firebase = 'webrtc-experiment';
```

PS. You may need to modify [config.xml](http://webrtcweb.com/cordova-apps/video-conferencing/#config.xml) to enable websocket or XHR_polling requests from `firebase.com`. Simply replace `rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com` with `firebase.com`. E.g.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-navigation href="https://firebase.com/*" />
        <allow-intent href="https://firebase.com/*" />
        <access origin="https://firebase.com" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: Hi Muaz Khan,
thanks for instant reply.
we are using Firebase for web-browser but we want to use same for IOS.

Comment: we are using Firebase for web-browser but we want to use same for IOS.
the RTCMultiConnection Demos cordva code in iOS app is using Socket.io
so is there any possibility that we can use Firebase for both.
or firebase for web-browser and socket.io for IOS.

Comment: when we trying to use firebase for ios in  cordova ,after room is  present we get error of unable to reach initiator no room present

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: We integrated the code successfully in cordova in IOS. and app found the created room. but facing error

Arguments ["Unable to reach initiator. Trying again..."] (1)
Arguments ["on:state:change (12345):", "room-not-available:", "Initiator seems absent. Waiting for someone to open the room."] (3)

Comment: Cordova-apps are compatible only with RTCMultiConnection-v3. [http://webrtcweb.com/cordova-apps/](http://webrtcweb.com/cordova-apps/)